# I want to write an arbitrary SQL query with R shiny multiple

Tags: sql, r, shiny

In this code, multiple selected columns of slectinput are fetched from SQL.

#### ui.R

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("select","select", 
                choices = c("ID","Name","CountryCode","District","Population"),
                multiple = TRUE),
    textOutput("sql_"),
    tableOutput("table")
  )
)
```

#### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
    output$table <- renderTable({
      sql <- paste('SELECT ', paste0("\"", input$select, "\"", collapse = ","),' FROM City;',seq = "")
      output$sql_ <- renderText(sql)
      query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql)
      dbGetQuery(pool, query)
    })
})
```

#### global.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(pool)

pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "shinydemo",
  host = "shiny-demo.csa7qlmguqrf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  username = "guest",
  password = "guest"
)
```

I think the sql syntax is correct. But I can't get it table. For some reason I get the column name. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are putting it into quotes, try this:

```
   q <- eventReactive(input$select,{
        query <- 'SELECT VARIABLES FROM City'
        query <- gsub("VARIABLES",paste0(input$select,collapse = ","),query) 
        query
    })

    output$sql_ <- renderText({
        q()
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
        query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, q())
        dbGetQuery(pool, query)
    })
```